# Linking 1 record from table A to multiple records from table B without PK/FK

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to link one record from a table A to multiple records from table B without having a FK/PK to eachother.

To be more specific: I have tableA with 3 records
`("regions","gender","citizenship")` and then I have `tableB` `"regions",tableC"gender",tableD "citizenship"`. Each of those tables don't have a FK.

The result I hope to achieve is another table `(E)` with the record `"regions"` from `tableA` linked to each record from `tableB`, then the record `"gender"` from tableA linked to each  records from `tableC`, e.t.c.

Is that possible? Which is the best way?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What do you mean by "link"?

Comment: Your question is not that clear. The good news, is that it seems pretty simple to do, if we actually clearly understand what you want to do. Can you add some data? A few rows will go a long way to help us understand.

Comment: Do you have some sort of identifying column in `B`, `C` and `D`? If so, you're just talking about a reference table, correct? You can use sqlfiddle.com or dbfiddle.uk to set up an example schema and data.

Comment: i assume all table have those columns you talked about and have other columns? You could be looking into table [Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ddl-inherit.html) which PostgreSQL natively supports.. Not sure if you need to have Inheritance relations it's not clear from the question.

Comment: To be more specific: Table_Target ("id_target",''des_target'', ''dat_target'') where id is the PK and des is the description of the record, then it will contain one record with the name ''region'', another one with ''gender'' and the last one with ''citizenship''. Table_Regions (''id_region'',''des_region'',dat_region'') id is PK and within the des_regions column there are the names of all the regions. It's the same for gender and citizenship.

Comment: What i want is a new table or a view with a 1 to many reletionship between the first record from table_target (''region'') and each records from table_regions, then between the second record from table_target and each records from table_gender and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you working on?

You should be able to JOIN these 3 tables regardless of them having PK/FK.

Primary & Foreign key constraints are there to help you manage, organize & query your tables in a more efficient way.

Although using these constraints may improve performance, the lack of them should not limit you from joining the data within the tables.

Comment: I'm working on Postgres. What i want to try is 1 to many relationship without having PK/FK.

Comment: You can accomplish that by JOINing the tables. The lack of PK/FK won't limit you here.

I could help you further if you share the queries or an example of the data

Comment: Is this just a learning exercise or do you have a reason for not wanting key relationships? PK/FKs do serve a purpose and make life easier, so I wouldn't suggest foregoing them just for the sake of not wanting to use them.

Comment: To be more specific:

Table_Target ("id_target",''des_target'', ''dat_target'') where id is the PK and des is the description of the record, then it will contain one record with the name ''region'', another one with ''gender'' and the last one with ''citizenship''.




Table_Regions (''id_region'',''des_region'',dat_region'') id is PK and within the des_regions column there are the names of all the regions. It's the same for gender and citizenship.

Comment: What i want is a new table or a view with a 1 to many reletionship between the first record from table_target (''region'') and each records from table_regions, then between the second record from table_target and each records from table_gender and so on.